# How to enable JavaScript in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using the UIWebview (IOS) to load my webview. A page of my site has a  link like that:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="insertClickPointDL('http://www.affil.jp/d/c.php?24unziqvz4bfp&guid=on&via=256&option=22399');" class="btn btn-large"><img src="http://devbit.cruzy.jp/wp-content/themes/BitCoinGet/assets/img/coin.png" height="26" width="26">このサービスを利用する</a>
```

When I clicked this link it showed log: NSURLErrorDomain error -999 and let me open the link with Safari browser.

When I view web with Webview (Android). It's OK.
Is it the reason that I don't enable JavaScript on IOS UIWebview like Android.
If yes, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is enabled by default with UIWebview. Can you tell us more about your issue? Are you trying to load a file or just display a webpage?

Comment: Image is not loaded in uiwebview
any solution for this??

<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<span>&nbsp;<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d481b5_8480692708be45aa8b285e2e40fe2047~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_700,h_220,al_c,lg_1,q_80/d481b5_8480692708be45aa8b285e2e40fe2047~mv2.webp" alt="" width="309" height="97" /></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span>Name Availability Check and Clearance</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Filing Documents of Formation</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Custom Operating Agreement</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Obtain EIN</p>